# Interacciones bot Discord en DM

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bot

Estoy intentando hacer un bot para Discord con node.js y discord.js v14. La verdad es que con JS no me llevo nada bien y voy un poco a ciegas.

Quiero hacer algo bastante sencillo:

-Cuando un usuario envíe un DM al bot (da igual el texto que el usuario ponga), que este le responda con una frase "A".

-El bot espera respuesta por parte del usuario durante 1 minuto:

--Si el usuario responde (da igual lo que responda), el bot responde con la frase "B"

---Al obtener respuesta vuelve a esperar otro minuto a que el usuario le responda

----En el caso de obtener respuesta (da igual lo que le ponga), el bot responde con la frase "C"

--Si no responde nada en alguno de los pasos anteriores, al finalizar el minuto responde con la frase "D"

La idea es luego poder añadir más frases por si el usuario sigue hablándole, siempre sin tener en cuenta lo que el usuario escriba.
Lo he intentado con .awaitMessages y .then:

```
  message.reply("Ahora mismo estoy liado...").then((initialReply) => {
    const filter = response => !response.author.bot;

    message.channel
      .awaitMessages({ filter, max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ["time"] })
      .then((collected) => {
        if (collected.size > 0) {
          initialReply.delete(); // Elimina la respuesta inicial del bot
          message.channel.send('Que parte de "Ahora mismo estoy liado..." no entiendes?');
        } else {
          message.channel.send("Así me gusta");
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        message.channel.send("Así me gusta");
      });
  });
}
```

y también de esta forma:

```
const replies = [
  "Respuesta inicial al primer mensaje.",
  "Respuesta a cualquier respuesta subsiguiente.",
  "Tercera respuesta.",
  "Cuarta respuesta."
];

const userStates = new Map(); // Mapa para almacenar el estado de los usuarios

  if (!message.guild && !message.author.bot) {
    if (!userStates.has(message.author.id)) {
      // Respuesta al primer mensaje de un usuario
      message.reply(replies[0]);
      userStates.set(message.author.id, 1);
    } else {
      const state = userStates.get(message.author.id);
      if (state < replies.length) {
        // Esperar la respuesta del usuario
        const filter = response => response.author.id === message.author.id;
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 60000 }); // Espera 60 segundos

        collector.on('collect', (response) => {
          const nextState = userStates.get(message.author.id);
          if (nextState < replies.length) {
            message.reply(replies[nextState]);
            userStates.set(message.author.id, nextState + 1);
          }

          collector.stop(); // Detiene el colector después de la respuesta
        });

        collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
          if (reason === 'time') {
            if (userStates.has(message.author.id)) {
              userStates.delete(message.author.id); // Elimina el estado del usuario si se acaba el tiempo
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Ninguna de las dos funciona correctamente, la primera responde siempre la primera frase y luego la primera frase seguida de la alternativa, y en la segunda siempre se obtiene como respuesta la primera frase.

Las constantes que tengo definidas son:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, ActivityType, Guild } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages
  ]
  ,
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.Message]
});
```

Siento el tocho de post. Si alguien puede echarme un cable, se lo agradecería.

¡Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin he dado con una solución que funciona correctamente (Discord.js v14).Lo pongo aquí por si a alguien le resultase útil:

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ]
});

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (!message.guild && !message.author.bot) {
    if (!message.author.replyState) {
      const replies = [
        "Respuesta-1",
        "Respuesta-2",
        "Respuesta-3",
        "Respuesta-4",
        "Respuesta-5",
        "Respuesta-6",
        "Respuesta-7",
        "Respuesta-8",
        "Respuesta-9",
        "Respuesta-10"
      ];

      message.reply(replies[0]);
      message.author.replyState = 1;

      const filter = response => response.author.id === message.author.id;
      const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({ filter, time: 60000 }); // Espera 60 segundos

      collector.on('collect', async (response) => {
        const currentState = message.author.replyState;

        if (currentState < replies.length) {
          message.reply(replies[currentState]);
          message.author.replyState++;
        }
      });

      collector.on('end', (collected, reason) => {
        if (reason === 'time') {
          message.reply("El tiempo para responder se ha agotado.");
          delete message.author.replyState;
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

// Iniciar sesión con el token
client.login('TU_TOKEN_AQUÍ');
```